Deserialize and serialize value object from JSON
In my project im using a value objects eg:
@Getter
@ToString
@Embeddable
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED, force = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor(staticName = "of")
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class EmailAddress {
    private final String value;

    public static String getValue(EmailAddress object) {
        if(object == null)
            return null;
        return object.value;
    }
}

Now I want tu use it in my api but I don't want have nasted objects in schema.
How can I configure JSON ? Have I write own serializer and deserializer ? What is the simpliest solution ?

Based on your tags I assume you are using Spring Boot. Spring Boot provides integration with three JSON mapping libraries, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/reference/features/json.html
The default library is Jackson, see https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson.
Spring Boot ships with an autoconfigration for Jackson, but you can write your own custom serializers and deserializers, if desired.
With default configuration Jackson provides different field annotations to manage/ control JSON (de-)serialization.
In your problem scenario you can use the following annotations:

@JsonIgnore: omit unnecessary fields by adding the annotation @JsonIgnore to the field. Jackson will then skip this field while (de-)serializing your object.
@JsonUnwrapped: unwrap/flatten field when (de-)serializing, see https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations#3-jsonunwrapped


But I want to return this value but in flatten version.

I edited my answer and added the annotation with explanation and link how to flat certain fields while deserialization in Jackson.
